# select data from mysql array

Tags: php, mysql

In my MySQL database I have an array column (text type) called `friend_array` where I have the variables `usernames` separated by comma (,)

for example: `user1` `friend_array` value in cell is:

```
prevert,
borges,
eliot,
wislawa,
derek,
hebert,
pushkin,
plath,
donnelly,
ahlberg,
ginsberg,
amiri,
rilke,
mckay,
aam,
wowen,
larkin,
michaux,
moliver,
dickinson,
rumi,
reverdy,
brecht,
tate,
cad,
cummings,
dianeb,
sexton,
redson,
pessoa,
transtromer,
shakespeare,
mistral,
sodergran,
bukowski,
auden,
tedhu,
ashton,
tomandrews,
gwallas,
updike,
ashbery,
jenkins,
rhass,
whitehead,
montale,
ritvo,
snyder,
kooser,
simic,
koertge,
nemerov,
aporter,
reichhold,
rduncan,
meretop,
kkoch,
strand,
kahf,
asha,
keats,
pinter,
santoka,
opaz,
breton,
schreiner,
bataille,
cedo,
galeano
```

now how to select each one of the friends separately in php in order to view friend list without repeating

thanks in advance

Comment: saving comma separated data is against NORMALIZATION rules and it will be very hard to do search, CRUD operation on those records. Try to save each `friend_array` data separately in db.

Comment: It seems you should read about the basics of relational databases. The question is not how to select, but how to store IMHO.

Comment: if data is in single key array you can try `$usernames[0]  = "prevert,borges,eliot,wislawa,derek,hebert,pushkin,plath,donnelly,ahlberg,ginsberg,amiri,rilke,mckay";
$pieces = explode(",", $usernames[0]);
echo $pieces[0];`

Comment: Related: [is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Answer (score 1):

You should create a new table `friend` that looks like this for example:

```
friend
===============
id_user | username
```

with a `primary key` on `id_user1 + username`, this way to get all friend of your `user1` you can just do `SELECT username FROM friend WHERE id_user = :id_user1;`. Having this kind of field with a string that contains multiple value you need to select is really bad practice as said in comment.

Now to answer the question, if you manage to get the `friend_array` value (a string with multiple username separate by comma as you said), you can do :

```
$data = explode(',', $your_friend_array_string);
```

If you want to remove duplicate :

```
$data_unique = array_unique($data);
```

Hope it helps, but start by changing the way you store your data it if possible !

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I absolutely agree you should absolutely work towards setting op relations and use normalization (ie: create a friends table). The question is if this is possible without making a repeating query.

It is like this:

```
SELECT
    a.name, 
    b.name 
FROM user a 
LEFT JOIN user b ON FIND_IN_SET(b.name, a.friends)
WHERE 
   a.name = 'name';
```

It's not pretty and if you have ANY way to edit the database structure you should do that and abandon this 'solution'.